# Regular and single action

Tags: present-tense

> I want to bring some tea

can mean both "bring some tea once" and "bring some tea every day". Am I right? Or it means only "bring some tea once" and if I want to say about regularity I have to use

> I want to bring some tea to you everyday

Comment: "I want to bring some tea" is a very strange thing to say, but nothing about the words themselves implies anything about whether the speaker wants to to whatever is it *once, twice a day for the next few weeks,* or *all day and every day, forever*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English requires context to convey the aspect of a verb, if it is ongoing and unfinished (perfect) or "once and done" (perfect).  Context can be so subtle, don't you think?

Your verb "bring" has the sense of being in the perfect aspect because of the  quantifier "some".  It could be a response to the question, "What do you want to bring to the lunch meeting?"  You want to bring some tea to this event.

It could have the imperfect aspect if it said something like, "I want to bring tea".  That leaves it more open-ended, as if you might be supplying tea for lunch meetings every week, or maybe just this one lunch meeting.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to know. "I want to bring some tea" can express perfect aspect and imperfect aspect, depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

I want to bring some tea to you everyday?
Although the above is a better choice, it is rather poor English.
Say it as: I wish to bring some tea to you everyday.
Why ? mark?
It isn't a question at all strictly speaking.
If you wish to make it interrogative say as
May I bring some tea to you everyday?